# How to test DE-115 with this example for writing C language

Tags: c, eclipse, intel-fpga

i use SOPC choose CPU, onchip memory 4096Bytes, LED, Switch,
then it auto generate following file, then i comment some code in test_bench,

and write to board, it only turn the light, i can not turn off with switch
then i open eclipse with SOPC, and genearte BSP, then build project and open flash programmer in eclipse, 
the start button is disable, and do not know where is compile and load button

```
module test_bench 
;


  wire             clk;
  reg              clk_0;
  wire    [  7: 0] in_port_to_the_Switches;
  wire             jtag_uart_0_avalon_jtag_slave_dataavailable_from_sa;
  wire             jtag_uart_0_avalon_jtag_slave_readyfordata_from_sa;
  wire    [  7: 0] out_port_from_the_LEDs;
  reg              reset_n;


// <ALTERA_NOTE> CODE INSERTED BETWEEN HERE
//  add your signals and additional architecture here
// AND HERE WILL BE PRESERVED </ALTERA_NOTE>

  //Set us up the Dut
  testsopc1 DUT
    (
      .clk_0                   (clk_0),
      .in_port_to_the_Switches (in_port_to_the_Switches),
      .out_port_from_the_LEDs  (out_port_from_the_LEDs),
      .reset_n                 (reset_n)
    );
/*
  initial
    clk_0 = 1'b0;
  always
    #10 clk_0 <= ~clk_0;

  initial 
    begin
      reset_n <= 0;
      #200 reset_n <= 1;
    end
*/
endmodule


#define Switches (volatile char *) 0x0003000
#define LEDs (char *) 0x0003010
int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        *LEDs = *Switches;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

**Update the project link**

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E0ED7271C68BE47C!361

when i open the project to build project again
it said RUN_ON_HDL_SIMULAGTOR_ONLY xxxx.elf error 1

then i build BSP again and build project again, it become make all complete
then i remember to make clean, it got the error again
and then build again

however, no matter what i do, i turn on or off switch, it only light turn on, and never off

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is your problem, but you only declared `Switches` volatile but not `Leds`. At it stands, it is perfectly reasonable for the compiler to eliminate the writes to hex 3010 as they seem to have no effect.

Try adding the volatile keyword to the second declaration.

Answer (score 1):

At this stage you don't need to use the flash programmer as you don't have a EPCS controller as of yet in your design as I remember the tutorial for LEDs and SWs. However one problem could be that you didn't do the correct pin configuration for the switches. Can you please share your SOPC design so we can take a look and see if the interconnect is correct?